# Best Practices for Automating Word Documents

Tags: programming-practices, automation, excel, word

I recently started at a company  as a Automation Developer. My job is to
automate periodic reports (in Word) for all of our customers (~50), one for each.
Each report is slightly different, so I am going to have develop code for each
company. The position is new and there are no automation in place; all reports are
compiled by copying data from Excel, pasting, and formatting in Word.

However, the data in all these reports all come from just 2 IT systems. 
I can set up the system to automatically send me Excel reports for each customers
on.

Here is my automation process for generating each report.

1. Create a template of the report which are striped away of tables, dates, and statistics.
2. Collect all data into one Excel workbook. (Different tables are in different worksheets.)
3. Ensure all tables are in a standard format.
4. Run a VBA script to compile all tables into a Word doc and populate 
   dates and statistics.

**Questions.**

1. Any recommendations for improving my current process?
2. What best practices should I follow when using VBA in Excel to automate reports?
3. How best to handle future changes?
4. Best way to transfer code amongst different users? And my users are not VBA-savvy; I will have to document how to automate these reports step-by-step.

Comment: Hy GTyler, your approach sounds fine, so if it works smooth for you, I do not see any problem which we can solve for you. Questions just asking for "best practices" or "I don't have a problem, but how can I improve?" will typically be closed on this site as "too broad". However, if you can narrow down your question and focus on the details of a problem you might have, then your question has chance to survive.

Comment: ... so to 1. Nope, no recommendations. 2. Could write a whole book about this, too broad. 3. similar as with any program: use version numbers, use version control, keep a strict separation between the program and user data, keep a change log. 4. You deliver each new version of the Excel document to your users (which you have separated from the data, see 3) by the established way of your company (common network drive, email, intranet, installer package, sharepoint server, whatever you like).

Answer (score 4):

Gain control of how report data is formatted.

Excel simply isn't a data format.  It has it's own presentation ideas.  You can make this work and it sounds like a lot has already been built help you do this.  So maybe you don't want to swim against the tide at this point but you're tied to a lot of things you don't want to be tied to.  Different versions of excel come out, different versions of VB savvy users come out.  Security concerns dictating disabling user access to VB scripts come out... on and on.

If the report is meant to be in MS word find the most direct way to put it into MS word.  If an excel report is also required find the most direct way to also put it in excel.  Using one to leverage the other invites Rube Goldberg and Murphy to come over and have party.

The 2 IT systems are where you should be getting reports from.  Get the most basic, flexible format from them you can and use that to make what you need.

Comment: From the OPs statement "I can set up the system to automatically send me Excel reports for each customers on" I conclude the OP *is already in control* of how the data is formatted, so though he did not clearly state where his problem is, that does not seem to be his problem.

Comment: @DocBrown yet we hear talk of using asking users to use excel scripts to write word.  That's not control.  That's taking what you get and trying to live with it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. IMHO the fact the formatting program is written in Excel VBA has absolutely nothing to do with the control the OP has about the input data - these are two different things.

Comment: @DocBrown I'm trying to tell you that using one report to generate another report is an antipattern.  Especially if you're making users do it.  We're told there are two IT systems where data is coming from. That's what reports should be generated from. Using VBA or something else.  Users shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: From the sentence "I can set up the system to **automatically** send **me** Excel reports" I would not come to the premature conclusion that 1) this is done manually by "the users", 2) the OP meant a "formatted report" (sounds more to me like Excel is just used as a data exchange format). However, I agree the role of "the users" is not clear in the OP's description, he should really clarify this (assumed he takes the time and makes his question more focussed).

Comment: What these 2 systems spit out are just data in tables. The final product is a Word doc with explanations and data from those systems. I am placing the data into one Excel workbook (serves as landing platform) and then run the VBA script to compile into a Word doc. Before users were just copying and pasting the data into Word; I am trying to eliminate that.

Comment: @Dombey And kudos to you for eliminating pointless busy work.  If your excel files are truly not separate reports with their own audience then I've no objection to using them, if there is no simpler path into word.  Here are two others: [CSV to word](https://support.groupquality.com/hc/en-us/articles/201221736-How-to-import-a-CSV-file-into-a-word-document) and [programatically create docx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656626/how-do-i-create-the-docx-document-with-microsoft-office-interop-word)

Comment: @CandiedOrange Thanks for the links. But I will try to keep it to VBA since users can just fire up Excel and access the code (if they are savvy enough). This helps with long-term maintenance.

Comment: @charlotte I'm leaning the same way.  I don't like users seeing excel if excel represents a report in the making. They'll just think of it as another report.  If excel is hidden from them then it's just another tool for the system to use.

Comment: @Dombey: thanks for the added information. However, I still miss to see where you have a problem we can solve for you. Your general approach seems fine to me (I implemented similar things in Excel VBA in the past more than once).

Comment: @charlotte and CandieOrange: The Excel workbook serves as a landing platform for the data from those 2 sources. And since it's Excel, users can run the VBA to generate that report.